# Problems with my registration page in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I might have a problem with my registration page. Everything is fine, but I can't understand why it needs to take so long to load the page for registration. This is just a registration document and it's called Registracija.html.

My question is which part in this code does that or what should I remove or add? I provided the CSS file so you can see full style of that page. Is there a problem with the CSS or something in the HTML document?

```css
/*css dokument*/ 
body {
 background-color: #ffffe6;
 align-self: 50px; 
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
 color: #751aff;
}
h2 {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #ff0000;
}
header, footer {
 padding: 1em;
 color: black;
 background-color: #a6a6a6;
 clear: left;
 text-align: center;
 color: #001a33;
}
p {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.dropbtn {
 background-color: #ff751a;
 color: white;
 padding: 16px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
}
.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffa366;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
 color: black;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #6699ff}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #ff944d;
}
.topnav {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #ff8000;
}
.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color:  #993d00;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ffc2b3; 
 color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
 background-color: #ffc2b3;
 color: white;
}
.button {
 background-color: #6699ff;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
 background-color: #ffa366;
 color: black;
}
div.question {
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ccddff;
 padding: 20px;
}
#div1 {
 font-size: 48px;
}
div.yexample {
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ffe0cc;
 padding: 20px;
}
.button2 {
 background-color: #ffa366;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 15px 32px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.button2:hover {
 background-color: #6699ff;
 color: black;
}
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#regForm {
 background-color: #ccddff;
 margin: 100px auto;
 font-family: Raleway;
 padding: 40px;
 width: 70%;
 min-width: 300px;
}
h3 {
 text-align: center; 
}
input {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Raleway;
 border: 1px solid #b3c6ff;
}
input.invalid {
 background-color: #ffdddd;
}
.tab {
 display: none;
}
button {
 background-color: #ffa366;
 color: white;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Raleway;
 cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
#prevBtn {
 background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
.step {
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 margin: 0 2px;
 background-color: #bbbbbb;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.set.active {
 opacity: 1;
}
.step.finish {
 background-color: #3377ff;
}
.registracija {
 color: black;
}
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0 12px 0;
}
img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.container {
    padding: 16px;
}
span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 30%;
    }
}
div.redbox {
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ffe0cc;
 padding: 20px;
}
div.bluebox {
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ccddff;
 padding: 20px;
}
.locationbtn {
 float: left;
 background-color: #3385ff;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.noone {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwo {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nothree {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nofour {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nofive {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nosix {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.noseven {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.noeight {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nonine {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.noten {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.noeleven {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwelve {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nothirteen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nofourteen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nofiveteen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nosixteen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.noseventeen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.noeighteen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nonineteen {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwenty {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentyone {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentitwo {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentythree {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentyfour {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentyfive {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentysix {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentyseven {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentyeight {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.notwentynine {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nothirty {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nothirtyone {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
.nothirtytwo {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 2px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv= "content-type" content= "text/html;  charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name= "description" content= "">
        <meta name= "keywords" content="">
        <meta name= "author" content= "Domagoj Ahmedovski">
        <meta name= "viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts-googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel= "shortcut icon" type= "image/x-icon" href= "favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> <!-- Kod za povezivanje html i css dokumenta (Registracija.html i style.css) -->
        <!--<link rel= "stylesheet" href= "css/style.css">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- Kod za responzivnu stranicu -->
<head>
    <title>Registracija</title>
<meta name="vewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Vrnuti se ovdje ako ne funkcionira -->
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h3>My web site</h3>
</header>
<center>
    <div class="topnav">
        <p align="right"><a href="index.html"><b>|</b>Home<b>|</b></a>
        <a href="Onama.html"><b>|</b>O nama<b>|</b></a>
        <a href="Queries.html"><b>|</b>Upiti<b>|</b></a>
        <a href="YourExample.html"><b>|</b>Vas Primjer<b>|</b></a>
        <a class="active" href="Registracija.html"><b>|</b>Registracija<b>|</b></a>
        <a href="Login.html"><b>|</b>Log in<b>|</b></a>
        <a href="Logout.html"><b>|</b>Log out<b>|</b></a></p>
    </div>
</center>
<br><br>
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="registracija"><h2>Registracija:</h2></div>
    <div class="tab">Ime:
        <p><input placeholder="Vaše ime" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Vaše prezime" oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Info kontakta:
        <p><input placeholder="E-mail" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Telefon" oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Rođenje:
        <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="mm"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Login:
        <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
</script>
<footer>
    Copyright &copy; Domagoj Ahmedovski
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS selectors are different but the CSS rules defined within are all the same.  Other than that, there's no good way for us to test how long it's actually taking to load the page and what we can do to improve it, since we cannot test out the HTML. Can you please provide information how "long" is "so long", and perhaps provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link to `https://fonts-googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway` is wrong.
It should be `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway`

If you use F12 in Chrome you can see that the request will fail.

Comment: if issue is typo related - it should be a comment and a vote to close^